# JAX-WS with Apache CXF under CDI/Weld

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, weld

I have seen the other questions on CXF under CDI but they all seem to be for JAX-RS style web services.

Is JAX-WS possible in this configuration? If not, how can I expose a JAX-WS service using CDI/Weld in a non-EE container (Tomcat 8)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CDI and JAX-WS in Tomcat then most possibly the easiest you can do is to use [Apache TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org/).

TomEE is basically a standard Apache Tomcat, but pimped with lots of JavaEE libs. It brings a full CDI container, JAX-RS, JAX-WS etc. 
For JAX-WS you should take the 'plus' variant.

If you want it really just embedded or smallish (in size, not in power), then you can also take a look at [Apache Meecrowave](https://openwebbeans.apache.org/meecrowave/) and bundle the JAX-WS part of CXF to it.

Meecrowave is a EE8 technology based smallish (9MB) Application Server which can be used standalone or embedded (via Meecrowave#bake()). It's pure Apache:
Tomcat (Servlets-4.0), OpenWebBeans (CDI-2.0), Johnzon (JSON-P_1.1, JSON-B_1.0), CXF, log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to enable CDI on tomcat. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_tomcat).

In my case, `@Inject` did not work on classes with `@WebService` but I was able to inject using `CDI.current().select(MyClass.class).get()`.

It did not work on `@PostConstruct` though, but you can use it inside a `@WebMethod`.

[Note] I was using [Metro](https://javaee.github.io/metro/) instead of Apache CXF